# Sorting custom dropdown in KendoUI grid

Tags: jquery, sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using  KendoUI Jquery grid. I have a custom combobox editor which is binded with a datasource.

My problem is I can sort the other columns of this grid perfectly, but this column on sorting give unexpected random results. Can anyone please help me how can I sort this column? code attached.

```
{ field: "Status", editor: statusDropDownEditor, template: '#=GetStatusColor(Status.Text)#', width: "90px" }

var statusData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [
            {  Text: "New", Value: "a9d59cd8-f569-45c4-bfdd-05f41db9e2f3" },
            {  Text: "Ready", Value: "e4aa129f-44b6-44e3-b5da-2ecc5c5c20c0" },
            {  Text: "Query", Value: "50b1af07-71a0-462f-86ec-a164d43a9b65" },
            {  Text: "Cancelled", Value: "79ee44ea-bc39-4a71-ad6d-c47886d0f69b" }
        ]
    });

function statusDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input data-text-field="Text" data-value-field="Value" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                autoBind: false,
                dataTextField: "Text",
                dataValueField: "Value",
                dataSource: statusData
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this solved using sample code from this link here.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/foreign-key-column-sorting-by-text

sample code snippet

```
  <script>
    var categories = [
        { "value": 1, "text": "Beverages"},
        { "value": 2, "text": "Condiments"},
        { "value": 3, "text": "Confections"},
        { "value": 4, "text": "Dairy Products"},
        { "value": 5, "text": "Grains/Cereals"},
        { "value": 6, "text": "Meat/Poultry"},
        { "value": 7, "text": "Produce"},
        {"value": 8, "text": "Seafood"}];

    //create dictionary of text-values for the FKC
    var categoriesDict = {};
    for (var i=0; i<categories.length;i++) {
        categoriesDict[categories[i].value] = categories[i].text;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
      var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        pageSize: 20,
        data: products,
        change: function(e) {
          if (!e.action) {
            this.data();
          }
        },
        schema: {
          model: {
            id: "ProductID",
            fields: {
              ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
              ProductName: { validation: { required: true} },
              CategoryID: { field: "CategoryID", type: "number", defaultValue: 1 },
              UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} }
            },
            //define calculated field:
            CategoryName: function() {
              return categoriesDict[this.get("CategoryID")];
            }
          }
        }
      });

      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        groupable: true,
        pageable: true,
        sortable: true,
        height: 540,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
          { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
          //bind column to the calculated field and specify custom editor:
          { field: "CategoryName()", width: "200px", title: "Category", editor: categoryDropDownEditor },
          { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "200px" },
          { command: "destroy", title: " ", width: "150px"}],
        editable: true
      });
    });


    function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
      //specify the value field in the "data-bind" attribute
      $('<input required data-text-field="text" data-value-field="value" data-bind="value:CategoryID"/>')
      .appendTo(container)
      .kendoDropDownList({
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: categories
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: While the link may answer the question, links change, so Stack Overflow prefers to not depend on them. [It would be better](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

the drop down by default sorts on the value field. Therefore your dropdown is being sorted on guids. To resolve this (if possible) you could refactor your code to use incremental integers (1,2,3,4) as the values of your datasource. I currently have the same problem and I have not found a way to configure the sorting of the drop down on the Text Field.